# Is it necessary to perform correction on confidence intervals of some specific coefficients of different models on same dataset?

Tags: r, regression, multiple-comparisons, bonferroni

I have a dataset which is about daily death rate of a specific disease and meteorological data:

The dataset structure is as below:

data =

| Death count | Daily pm2.5 (lag 0) | Daily pm2.5 (lag 1) | Daily pm2.5 (lag 2) | covariates |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13 | 99 | NA | NA | ... |
| 19 | 78 | 99 | NA | ... |
| 16 | 66 | 78 | 99 | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Three regressions models are run as below:

$$Death\;count \thicksim Daily\;pm2.5\,(lag 0) \; -----model1$$
$$Death\;count \thicksim Daily\;pm2.5\,(lag 1) \; -----model2$$
$$Death\;count \thicksim Daily\;pm2.5\,(lag 2) \; -----model3$$

The coefficients of $Daily\;pm2.5\,(lag\,i)\,$will be extracted for interpreting the result across different lags. Is it necessary to perform multiple comparisons in the above three models?

The research question is to determine the lag effects of PM2.5 to Death.
The first step is to run 3 regression on the same dataset with different lagged variable.
The second step is to extract the coefficients of the lagged variables and their confidence intervals and plot a error plot, then interpret their results (i.e. interpret the relative risk corresponding to different lag i).
[image]

The plot will be similar to the above graph, the x-axis should be `lag` variable.

Since I extracted multiple estimates and confidence intervals from the multiple models, should I perform some correction?

I am not sure whether it is a multiple-comparison question or not.

Comment: What do you mean by "Is it necessary to perform multiple comparisons"?

Comment: @Roland I have added more details about the research question.

Comment: It is still unclear. Nowhere do you mention p-values, which might need to be corrected for multiple comparisons. However, you are probably asking the wrong question. I would question why you can't fit a model including all three lags or use a proper timeseries (ARMA) model. I don't understand how your research question would lead to a multiple comparison problem.

Comment: I have tried to fit a model including all three lags, but the collinearity of the lagged variables is so high that the estimates of those three variables are biased.  ARMA is not a good choice since it cannot capture the nonlinear effect. I have tried DLNM but the selection of appropriate spline is complicated. So I tried another approach to model the effect.

Comment: First, while I am not any kind of expert on time series, a 10 second Google search found articles using ARMA with spline functions.  Second, you have a count as the DV, you may need to use a count model. Third, I agree with @Roland regarding the multiple comparisons aspects.

Comment: Would you mind to explain more why it is not a multiple-testing problem?

Comment: I have already figured out what models I need to use, 1. Distributed lag non-linear model; 2. Time-stratified conditional poisson regression. I prefer to use the latter one since it is easier to interpret...